# Minted environment returning blank after compile

Tags: beamer, minted, python

I want to display the following computer code in Latex:
But when I compile I get nothing at all!

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usetheme{Berkeley}%{Marburg}

    
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \vskip4em%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%

  \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \defbeamertemplate*{sidebar right}{sidebar theme}
    {%
      \vfill%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
´      \vskip2pt}  \fi

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{\insertsectionheadnumber
~\insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{\insertsectionheadnumber
~\insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{Python}

from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq, plot 

r = Symbol('r') 

s = Symbol('s')

equation = Eq(r**0.6 * s**0.4, 8.79)

sol = solve(equation, s) 

s_of_r = sol[0]

for ri in range(3, 19):

    si = s_of_r.subs(r, ri).evalf()
    
    print(f"for r={5-ri*.25} the corresponding value for s={5-si*.25:.6f}")
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is how it comes out when I compile:

[image: my document]

The `_` and `{` symbols are not displaying.

I have also invoked the -shell-escape flag
[image]

Comment: you mention minted but you are not using minted or even a simple verbatim environment: just entering the code as normal text paragraphs. If (as here) you get an error you should ask about the error message, any pdf generated if you scroll past the error is not intended to be usable.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I had forgotten to add the code environment. However, it is existing in my latex document.

Comment: presumably you are also missing `\documentclass{beamer}`  please always provide a real example and show the output and any error messages from the code as posted. I get `! Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete`  from your code if I add the documentclass  unless I use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post to include my document class--Beamer, as you guessed. I do not get an error when I compile. It could be because it is necessary to have Python installed on one's computer to use the `Minted` package.

Comment: No I have python and minted, It is impossible that you get the output that you show without getting an error.

Comment: Hi David, I have implemented your suggestion. Unfortunately, when I compile, the frame returns blank. Do you know why that could be. I am using TexMaker. I have updated the question to show more of my preamble.

Comment: The code you posted was missing `\end{document}` If I add that, your modified preamble generates the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@sidebar right@sidebar theme already defin
ed.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` which is not releated to the original question (or to minted)

Comment: are you using `--shell-escape` flag to pdflatex to allow it to run python/pygmetize?

Comment: Yes. I think I will try a different environment.

Comment: if you provide a test file and provide the log file showing the error you get then someone can debug. Without that there is no more help we can really give other than my answer which answered the original question before the edit. LaTeX will not make "nothing at aall" or the output that you showed in the image without making an error message in the log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

verbatim-like environments need a `[fragile]` frame:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}%{Marburg}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{Python}

from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq, plot 

r = Symbol('r') 

s = Symbol('s')

equation = Eq(r**0.6 * s**0.4, 8.79)

sol = solve(equation, s) 

s_of_r = sol[0]

for ri in range(3, 19):

    si = s_of_r.subs(r, ri).evalf()
    
    print(f"for r={5-ri*.25} the corresponding value for s={5-si*.25:.6f}")
\end{minted}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```